# My button doesn't apear after the initial popup - Python Message Box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, messagebox

I'm trying to make a little pop-up interface before my game to choose difficulties. The problem I'm having is that after I click yes on the first `messagebox.askyesno()` the whole pop up disappears and I have no idea on how to know which button was pressed to return an output. This is my first time using **tkinter** and **messagebox** so any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def start_game():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    if messagebox.askyesno("Welcome to Snake!", "Would you like to play?") == True:
        mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a dificulty:')
        easy_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Easy')
        medium_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Medium')
        hard_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Hard')

        mainLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        easy_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        medium_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        hard_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    root.deiconify()
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()

    root.mainloop()

start_game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about an `else` statement ;-)? Consider what your code is doing: if you click 'Yes', it creates some Button on a main window that you have withdrawn. Then, immediately after you deiconify it, you destroy it. Reshuffle your code like follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def start_game():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    if messagebox.askyesno("Welcome to Snake!", "Would you like to play?") == True:
        root.deiconify()                    # <--- deiconify under the True condition
        mainLabel = tk.Label(root, text='Choose a dificulty:')
        easy_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Easy')
        medium_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Medium')
        hard_ask = tk.Button(root, text='Hard')

        mainLabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        easy_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        medium_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        hard_ask.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    else:
        root.destroy()                       # <--- destroy and quit under the False condition
        root.quit()

    root.mainloop()

start_game()
```

**Note** that you can also assign the outcome of `messagebox.askyesno` to a variable:

```
answer = messagebox.askyesno("Welcome to Snake!", "Would you like to play?")
```